# dojox/form/Manager onSubmit fires more than once

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I have declared a class based on dgrid/OnDemandGrid. The class can display a selected record for editing using dojox/form/Manager, which I have placed in a dijit/Dialog. When editing the first record everything works fine, but subsequent submits seem to accumulate and fire the submit event repeatedly, although the put method only seems to get called once per submit.

Please see the Firebug output here http://speedyshare.com/hQBuP/submitRecord.png (just click the file name at the top)

The edit and submit methods look like the code below. Any suggestions to what is wrong with my code are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

```
editRecord: function() {
    this.editMode = "edit";

    var rec = this.store.get(currentRowId);
    var form = registry.byId(this.editFormId);
    var dialog = registry.byId(this.dialogId);

    form.reset();
    form.setFormValues(rec);
    form.on("submit", lang.hitch(this, this.submitRecord));

    var cancelButton = registry.byId(this.cancelButtonId);
    dialog.show().then(function(){cancelButton.focus();});
},

submitRecord: function(event) {
    // Testing counter
    if(!this.counter)
        this.counter = 1;
    else
        this.counter++;
    console.log("Submit event: " + this.counter);

    // Get form, dialog and retrieve record
    var form = registry.byId(this.editFormId);
    var dialog = registry.byId(this.dialogId);

    // Check validity
    if(!form.validate()) {
            return false;
    }

    var rec = form.gatherFormValues();

    // Put record in store  
    this.store.put(rec).then( /*..... pop up status or error toaster (code omitted)..*/ );

    // Dismiss dialog
    form.reset();
    dialog.hide();

    // Stop submit event
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();    
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching a `submit` event listener every time `editRecord` is called, which is presumably every time you show your dialog.  You really only want to be attaching that listener once.  Since you're never removing it and adding it every time, you're effectively causing the same function to fire n+1 times on the next submit after each time `editRecord` is called.  Hook up the submit event handler exactly once after creating the form instead.

If I had to guess, the reason `store.put` is only being called once is because you reset the form afterwards, so subsequent repetitive calls to `submitRecord` will fail the `validate` call and bail out before the `put` call.